# Need To route to different SSO based on user checkbox

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, login, mydomain, loginflow

i have two sso setup in my org.
1.OneWay
2.TwoWay

My requirement

on each user there is a check box.
If that checkbox is true then i need to route that user to OneWay sso login flow.If not then i have to route that user to TwoWay SSO.

How can i accomplish this.please suggest

Example:Once user entered his Fed Id in login page
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [My Domain Login Discovery](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_login_discovery.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes I started working using Login Discovery.Query is Once i enetered the Fedration identinfier in login page based on conditions it will redirect it to perticular sso .but there again i need to enter the FedrationIdentifier and then password.IS there any way to avoid entering this twice

Comment: You might want to post this as a new question or edit this one.